# How do I align my text and button to the center in CSS?

Tags: css

So I'm trying to recreate this template for practice:

https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/

I have a link to codepen for the code. I hope that's okay:

https://codepen.io/wmufunde/pen/geQaWg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Start Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id = "welcome">
            <h2>Welcome to our Studio!</h2>
            <h1>It's nice to Meet you!</h1>

            <button>Tell me More</button>
        </div>
    </header>

    Services
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.

<div class = "row">
   <div class = "col">
       <h3>Features</h3>
   </div>
   <div class = "col">
       <h3>Easy to Learn and Design</h3>
   </div>
   <div class = "col">
       <h3>Boostrap 3</h3>
</div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>

html, header {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    background-image: url(/portfolio-practice/img/flowers.jpg);
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
}

 header h1, h2 {
   /* text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 90px; */
}

button {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fed136;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family:sans-serif, 'Comic sans';

}

#welcome {
    display: flex;
     align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
    background: #212529;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I managed to align the text just fine without flexbox earlier with the commented out code, but I was informed that I'd have to use flexbox for the button to align in the center. Is this true? If so how do I get it to work correctly? It's been a while since I've used flexbox. Would it be easier to use absolute positioning?

What I want is to get the h1, h2 and button each on a new line. How do I do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `flex-direction: column`. Please update your css for `id='welcome'` as bellow,

```
#welcome {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I get the text and button to go in the center of the header though?

Comment: I am unclear about what you want to accomplish. Please elaborate it or show some example.

Comment: On this website the words "Welcome to our studio! It's nice to meet you" is in the center of the screen. How do I accomplish this please? Here is the website: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/

Comment: You are already doing it with `align-items: center`. The [link you provided](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/),  actually not positioning it in window center, rather it has a fixed height.
Please try resizing your browser window to understand what I am saying.

You can use `height: ` property to give your flex container some fixed height.

More reference see [w3 school flexbox examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)